# Strange issue inserting newline inside MS Word 2007 Table via C# Environment.NewLine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-word, newline, shared-addin

I created a Shared AddIn using Visual Studio 2008, C#. In the AddIn, I get data from a database, populate it into a Dictionary object, and use Word's builtin FindReplace to replace text inside a WordTemplate with the data from the database.

```
  Dictionary<string, string> myDBData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Some of the db fields need the newline character (i.e. multi-line data), so I insert a newline using **Environment.NewLine** in my code before passing the dictionary object to a find-replace routine.

The problem is, for fields that have the newline character in them, the text is getting replaced properly inside the world template ***only if*** the [replacemefieldname] placeholder is ***outside a Word Table*** like so.

These 12 lines are outside A MS WORD Table:

Firm

Firm

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

Fluid

If the  [replacemefieldname] placeholder is inside a MS Word Table, the the multiple text string is rendering in a single line like so.

Firm  Firm  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid  Fluid

See following screenshot for both rendering (inside and outside table).

If I copy the table text and paste outside, then also the new lines render properly!!

**So what other characters besides Environment.NewLine should I be placing in between the lines in the string before passing it on to Word to do find-replace for [replacemefieldname] placeholders that exist inside a MS Word Table ?**

thank you

ps. The clever folks at StackOverflow are preventing me from posting screenshot since I'm deemed a "New User", so here  is the screenshot that makes my question clearer.. :)

http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/144/wrderr.png

Comment: See that pilcrow button (the paragraph symbol) in the Ribbon? Click that and post another screen shot.

Comment: Is this the screen shot you are asking for ?

http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/2750/wrderrwithspecialchars.png

It shows the special characters.

Note that it does not show the newline characters in the text inside the table cell, however, if I simply copy cell contents using control+C and paste using Control+V, viola! the text is rendered with the newLine. baffling.

Comment: Here is an actual Test Word Document, with the content (inside table, outside table) for you to check out and help...

http://mycodetrip.com/Table-Issue-WordDoc.docx

thank you